# Javascript onclick does not work, multiple images to click in a row

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I've tried to combine code I found (I don't know JS too well), and I click on the image in the DOM (mockup2.png),  but nothing happens. It is supposed to go to mockup3.png, and then another click takes it to mockup4.png etc. For context, some of the other code is using Bootstrap and Razor. Any idea why the clicking does nothing?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Marketplace";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Login.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site.css" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#studentnavicons a').hover(
            function () {
                $("#studentnaviconstext p").text($(this).attr("title"));
            }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('wireframe-student');
    var img = <img src="~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup2.png" />;
    var img1 = <img src="~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup3.png" />;
    var img2 = <img src="~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup4.png" />;
    var img3 = <img src="~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup5.png" />;

    checkbox.onclick = function () {
        if (checkbox.src == img) {
            checkbox.src = img1;
        } else if (checkbox.src == img1) {
            checkbox.src = img2;
        } else if (checkbox.src == img2) {
            checkbox.src = img3;
        } else {
            checkbox.src = img3;
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="background">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <h1 class="student-header" align="center">Marketplace</h1>
            <div id="studentnavicons">
                <a href="~/Student/Default" title="Store"><i class="fas fa-store-alt" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
                <a href="~/Student/Community" title="Community"><i class="fas fa-map-signs" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
                <a href="~/Student/Market" title="Marketplace"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
                <a href="~/Student/Accomplishments" title="Yep, I did this"><i class="fas fa-trophy" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
                <a href="~/Student/Avatar" title="Avatar"><i class="fas fa-user" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
                <a href="~/Portal/Logout" title="Logout"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="boxed" align="center">
                    <font size="10">Points: 150</font>
                </div>
                <img id="wireframe-student" src="~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup2.png" width="1000" class="img-responsive"  />

                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <div style="float: right; margin-top:-70px;" align="center">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Sell", "MarketAfter", "Student", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div style="float:right; margin-top:-70px;" align="center">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Buy", "MarketAfter", "Student", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Trying the JQuery, but still nothing:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Marketplace";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Login.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site.css" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $('#studentnavicons a').hover(
                function () {
                    $("#studentnaviconstext p").text($(this).attr("title"));
                }
    });
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

    $('#wireframe-student').on('click', function () {
        var img_src = $(this).attr('alt');
        if (img_src == 'image1') {
            $(this).attr({ src: '/Content/img/Student Market/Market_demo3.png', alt: 'image2' });
        } else if (img_src == 'image2') {
            $(this).attr({ src: '/Content/img/Student Market/Market_demo4.png', alt: 'image3' });
        } else if (img_src == 'image3') {
            $(this).attr({ src: '/Content/img/Student Market/Market_demo5.png', alt: 'image4' });
        } else {
            /* carry on..... */
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="background">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <h1 class="student-header" align="center">Marketplace</h1>
        <div id="studentnavicons">
            <a href="~/Student/Default" title="Store"><i class="fas fa-store-alt" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
            <a href="~/Student/Community" title="Community"><i class="fas fa-map-signs" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
            <a href="~/Student/Market" title="Marketplace"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
            <a href="~/Student/Accomplishments" title="Yep, I did this"><i class="fas fa-trophy" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
            <a href="~/Student/Avatar" title="Avatar"><i class="fas fa-user" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
            <a href="~/Portal/Logout" title="Logout"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" style="color:#7a553b"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="boxed" align="center">
                <font size="10">Points: 150</font>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <img id="wireframe-student" src="/Content/img/Student Market/Market_demo2.png" width="1000" class="img-responsive" alt="image1" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

                <div style="float: right; margin-top:-70px;" align="center">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Sell", "MarketAfter", "Student", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div style="float:right; margin-top:-70px;" align="center">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Buy", "MarketAfter", "Student", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing this

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('wireframe-student');
    var img = <img src="~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup2.png" />;
    var img1 = <img src="~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup3.png" />;
    var img2 = <img src="~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup4.png" />;
    var img3 = <img src="~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup5.png" />;
```

to

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('wireframe-student');
var img = "~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup2.png";
var img1 = "~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup3.png";
var img2 = "~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup4.png";
var img3 = "~/Content/img/Student Market/market_mockup5.png";
```

i changed the code in the second block you can refer it here

https://jsfiddle.net/3pan85xv/

just the after click part more readable then if else loop

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

    $('#wireframe-student').on('click', function () {
        var img_src = $(this).attr('alt');

        switch(img_src){

          default : 
         case 'image1': $(this).attr({ src: '/Content/img/Student Market/Market_demo3.png', alt: 'image2' });
                                break;
          case 'image2': $(this).attr({ src: '/Content/img/Student Market/Market_demo4.png', alt: 'image3' });
                                break;

           case 'image3': $(this).attr({ src: '/Content/img/Student Market/Market_demo5.png', alt: 'image4' });
                  break;




        } 
    });
    });
</script>
```

new fiddle with the changes i just did https://jsfiddle.net/shyamjoshi/qoa3jfq1/1/

Comment: When you run the second code block does the image remain same or it goes blank ?

Comment: if you are using jquery you need to wrap it in here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3pan85xv/

Comment: That's jQuery worked thanks!! Gosh, I want to give you both the right answer. It was a combination. If you rewrite the jQuery I will mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this jQuery code.
For easy understanding keep short image name in img's alt tag
to differentiate on each click and change image name on each click for next image.
I hope this will help..!

```js
$('#wireframe-student').on('click', function(){
    var img_src = $(this).attr('alt');
    if(img_src == 'image1') {
        $(this).attr({src:'http://via.placeholder.com/150x160',alt:'image2'});
    } else if(img_src == 'image2') {
        $(this).attr({src:'http://via.placeholder.com/150x170',alt:'image3'});
    } else if(img_src == 'image3') {
        $(this).attr({src:'http://via.placeholder.com/150x180',alt:'image4'});
    } else {
        /* carry onn..... */
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img id="wireframe-student" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="" class="img-responsive" alt="image1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks so nice, but I still cannot get the image to move. I click and nothing happens. I will update my code, if you want to look. I'll add it as a 2nd code block.

Comment: 1. Check alt="image1" in this image tag : <img id="wireframe-student" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="" class="img-responsive" alt="image1" /> It identifies your fist image with default image source.  2. if..else in js determining current visible clicked image. 3. observe this js line $(this).attr({src:'http://via.placeholder.com/150x160',alt:'image2'}); . you need to put full image source next to src: (in quotes) and alt: to 'image2'.  Note : point 3 is for replacing current image source with next image, so you need to change its text in alt tag too (for next img to work fine)